# Is there any way to obtain the abandonware 1994 original release of Klik & Play in non-English, non-"For Schools" versions?

Tags: ibm-pc, software, windows-3.x

In the mid-1990s, I purchased a Swedish boxed copy of v1.0 (I believe) of Klik & Play in a computer store. Since that, the floppies have died and I stupidly even threw away the entire big box and manual, which I now bitterly regret.

It's trivial to find a "Klik & Play For Schools" online to download, in English. But that's not the version I had. I don't care if the only difference was a slight change of the splash screen -- it wasn't the one I had!

I'm also aware that there is a "1.1" version of it, but again, it's in English. My version was in Swedish, because it was sold in Sweden in an era where they still cared about translating software (or anything).

I'm thus looking for a Swedish-language, v1.0 Klik & Play (or KNP as it's frequently abbreviated). This is hopeless to find, apparently, since I've spent many years regularly searching but only finding the "For Schools" crap in English, or even the non-"For Schools" one in English.

Even if this is probably technically piracy, they have not sold that program for eons, and I did buy a copy long ago, so I have the moral right to re-experience it digitally as far as I'm concerned.

PS1: If there is "only" a Swedish v1.1, that will do as well. It's still much better than "For Schools" and/or English language! And frankly, I'm not 100% sure that my copy was 1.0. It *could* have been the v1.1 that I had.

PS2: I'm unsure what exactly was different about the "For Schools" edition. AFAIK, it was the exact same program, no differences, just with a "freeware" license.

PS3: I'm **not** asking for the serial number that the installer asks you for to install the program.

Comment: I am not very sure, but intellectual property laws might be not valid for such an old product. You have some chance with torrent.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica I never find anything on BitTorrent sites, sadly. Used to have some stuff in the early 2000s, but nowadays... nothing.

Comment: Because google is full with trashbox torrent site listings. Practically you can not search for torrent with google. But there are some good torrent sites, too. Maybe searching on tor might also help. Well, I admit, so is it already not easy.

Comment: [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/win3_kpschool) has an English version, making likely that the software can already be legally distributed. If you are really hardcore guy, you might download it and translate the strings in the binary code with a hexa editor :-)

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Yes, that's the "For Schools" edition, and in English...

Comment: This question may fall under https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/166/

Comment: @user3840170 If it does, it can still be answered in an on-topic way, so it should be fine. (That meta post is recommended reading, though; I'd forgotten about it.)

Comment: I've got an old CD lying around actually and the silkscreen print is in Swedish, though it doesn't state the version number. I'm a bit short of CD players for imaging these days but given a postal address I'd be happy to drop it in the mail for you, amazingly I can even recite the key code by heart these 25 years later despite normally barely remembering my own phone number. No guarantees as to whether or not it has suffered bit rot..

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because to assist here is piracy.

Comment: @peterferrie - Technically, the posted question could be answered with a yes or no response, while not assisting in piracy at all.  A reference might be trickier, though.  Perhaps a screen shot of the software running, or of the download page and link with the TLD hidden, or of the file sitting in the "Downloads" tab of their browser...